# loop over 2 sets of worksheets, perform calculations, and populate 3rd set of worksheets

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I'm trying to compare data across worksheets. I have values from `C14` to `C19` in worksheet 1.a and worksheet 1.b. I'm trying to use a `for each loop` to subtract the cells in column `C` in worksheet 1.a from the cells in column `C` in worksheet 1.b, and populate the results in column `C` on worksheet 1.c. I'm trying to use loops for this process because I have 50 worksheets with an a and b version. The below vba code populates the first two worksheet #.c with results but fails on all of the other worksheet #.c. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Here is the structure of the code:

```
    Sub DataSubtract()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim sheet_name As Range
    Dim sheet_name2 As Range
    Dim sheet_name3 As Range
    Set sheet_name2 = Sheets("WS_QA").Range("B:B")
    Set sheet_name3 = Sheets("WS_QA").Range("C:C")

    'Counter 1
    Dim counter As Long
    counter = 1
    'Counter 2 for sheet_name3
    Dim counter2 As Long
    counter2 = 1

    'Row
    Dim r As Long

    For Each sheet_name In Sheets("WS_QA").Range("A:A")
        If sheet_name.Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            With Sheets(sheet_name.Value)
            'Column C
                For r = 14 To 39
                .Cells(r, 3).Value = Sheets(sheet_name2(counter, 1).Value).Cells(r, 3).Value - Sheets(sheet_name3(counter2, 1).Value).Cells(r, 3).Value
                counter = counter + 1
                counter2 = counter2 + 1
                Next r
            End With
        End If
    Next sheet_name
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Best regards,

Comment: Right now `counter` and `counter2` are doing the exact same thing.  Should `counter2` be outside the for loop?  And I am guessing you want to reset the counters to 1 for each sheet

Comment: Yes, guess I don't need the second counter at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the initialization of `counter` to inside the `for each` loop so that it gets reset each time you get to a new sheet.  Also get rid of that second counter since you don't need it.

```
Sub DataSubtract()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim sheet_name As Range
    Dim sheet_name2 As Range
    Dim sheet_name3 As Range
    Set sheet_name2 = Sheets("WS_QA").Range("B:B")
    Set sheet_name3 = Sheets("WS_QA").Range("C:C")

    'Counter 1
    Dim counter As Long

    For Each sheet_name In Sheets("WS_QA").Range("A:A")
        counter = 1
        If sheet_name.Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            With Sheets(sheet_name.Value)
            'Column C
                For r = 14 To 39
                .Cells(r, 3).Value = Sheets(sheet_name2(counter, 1).Value).Cells(r, 3).Value - Sheets(sheet_name3(counter, 1).Value).Cells(r, 3).Value
                counter = counter + 1
                Next r
            End With
        End If
    Next sheet_name
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```